# In Java for android which is faster more efficient

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

Say I have a list of strings or whatever really. Then say I want to use **ONE** of the strings multiple times in the next bit of code. Should I create a new String variable foo `String foo = list.get(position)` and use `foo` in the following code, or should I save the memory space and use `list.get(position)` every time I need to use that string? Or are they actually the same thing under the hood?

Would the answer change if the list contained a more complicated class that might do a lot of computations to instantiate or have a lot of variables in itself so creating a new one takes up a lot of memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list only holds references to the items it contains, not the items themselves.

When you write `SomeObject s = list.get(0);` you simply retrieve a reference to the object and the memory used is either 32 or 64 bits depending on the device. And since the get operations is extremely fast (essentially an array access), the answer is that it makes almost no difference* (but using a variable might be slightly faster).

From a readability perspective it is generally better to use an extra variable and give it a self-explanatory name.

*assuming you use an ArrayList: for other list implementations, the cost of a `get` might be significant.

Comment: I agree that from readability perspective it is more convenient to use an intermediate variable, but when you use extra variable, you allocate one extra object on the heap - one extra string

Comment: No you don't - as explained in my answer a variable is a reference (= pointer) to an object not the object itself. In `String s = "ABC"; String s2 = s;` there is only one string object, but two references to it.

Comment: If the list is, by any chance, shared across threads - better to get the reference & hold for the immediate "use case".

Comment: Your initial analysis assumes an `ArrayList`, but doesn't hold for a `LinkedList`.  It's just *better* to grab the value and hold the reference.

Comment: @RichardSitze yes indeed.

Comment: Nice to know that a new variable is just a reference, I'll stick to creating a new string when I need it multiple times. If not just for readability sake.

Answer (score 4):

Get the value once, and hold it for the life of your use-case:

1. The *memory cost* for holding a reference is *minimal*, and less than the cost, in byte-code, of *N extra* invocations of `list.get(0)` for some small *N* (likely 2, if not 1).  Granted, the cost may be in a different area of memory.
2. The *runtime cost* for `list.get(0)` should not be assumed to be very fast (**O(1)**).  Such an assumption is based on an underlying `ArrayList`; it's **O(N)** for a `LinkedList`.
3. If your code does, or ever will, run in a multi-threaded environment, then:

   - `list` may change behind the scenes.
   - The cost of a (protected) `get` will go up.
4. As mentioned by assylias, it's better style to give the value a meaningful name.